# appending to an existing excel file

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

I have this function which writes and saves to an excel file. What I want to do now is append to that same existing excel file.This is the function:

```
private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//creates excel file and writes data to it
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        if (xlApp == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Excel is not properly installed!!");
            return;
        }

        if (System.IO.File.Exists("cross_check.xls"))
        {



        }
        else
        {


            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            IndexProp += 1; 
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[IndexProp, 1] = comboBox2.Text;
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[IndexProp, 2] = textBox5.Text;
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[IndexProp, 3] = textBox2.Text;
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[IndexProp, 4] = comboBox3.Text;
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[IndexProp, 5] = textBox3.Text;
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[IndexProp, 6] = comboBox1.Text;


            xlWorkBook.SaveAs(@"cross_check.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
            xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xlApp.Quit();

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);

            MessageBox.Show("Excel file created succcessfully");
        }

    }
}
```

This particular block is checking for the file if it exists and then does the append operation if it exists. How do I do this?

```
 if (System.IO.File.Exists("cross_check.xls"))
        {



        }
```

Comment: Unless you are using Excel features it would be much easier to create, and append to, a .CSV file that Excel can easily work with. I've found Interop to be difficult, especially if the program runs on different PCs. If you do have Excel functions you need I'd next try using VBA in Excel to do the work. Interop would be my last choice.

Comment: @rheitzman The problem is I plan to load this excel file into a data grid after so having it in a .CSV file may be problematic after awhile

Answer (score 1):

You would want to open the file make it the active work book and then make any changes you want. From there you can save it or do what ever you want with it.

Comment: To rephrase: I want to keep adding then save the file. Forgive me but am not verse on excel interloping. Usually I would work with text files and just open and whenever am finished the file closes and saves with the name initially created with. But in this case from examples am seeing that the excel file saves at the end of each operation. How do I keep it open and continue adding?

Comment: There's really no difference in how you would append to an excel file. You do it the same way you do it with text files. If the file exists open it
 
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("filename", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);

Comment: C# interop will just write what ever commands you give it. It doesn't save the document unless you call save just like how it would work if a user was appending it manually. Not sure what you mean by saves at the end of each operation.

Comment: Yeah but I didn't call it and when I look for that file it doesn't exist so it seems to me without the save operation it gives me a problem

Comment: When you run your current code does it create a document? If the file doesn't exist you obviously cant append to it. It's not really clear what exactly your problem is.